# Angular.js vs Knockout.js vs Backbone.js

Tags: angularjs, backbone.js, knockout-2.0

I am considering to use either Knockout or Angular or  Backbone for my personal project. I need to build some bigger, longer-running client-side interactions to go with my server-side stuff.

I want a simple and effective way to manage data-driven user interfaces.

Which framework would you choose to solve my problem described above based on the feasibility as well as the performance aspect?

Answer (score 112, accepted):

It depends on the nature of your application. And, since you did not describe it in great detail, it is an impossible question to answer. I find Backbone to be the easiest, but I work in Angular all day. Performance is more up to the coder than the framework, in my opinion.

Are you doing heavy DOM manipulation? I would use jQuery and Backbone.

Very data driven app? Angular with its nice data binding.

Game programming? None - direct to canvas; maybe a game engine.

Comment: Backbone with Facebook's [React.js](http://facebook.github.io/react/) is another alternative. See [Clay Allsopp's article](https://usepropeller.com/blog/posts/from-backbone-to-react/) for a good overview about use with Backbone.

Comment: Isn't jquery not very fast for heavy DOM manipulating?

Comment: @quux now jQuery became a low level language as compare to other JS framework, these framework like  Angular/BackboneJs provides rich interface to handle dom/data