# For asp.net mvc which js best either AngularJs or BackboneJs or KnockOutJs?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, backbone.js, knockout.js

I am working in Asp.net MVC for last 1 year but I have never used AngularJs , BackboneJs or KnockoutJs . Now I want to use it in my project but I am little bit confuse that for MVC which is one is Best . Somewhere I read that AngularJs has best perfomance but mostly used with MVVM framework so kindly provide me proper guidance that with Asp.net MVC which js is best either  AngularJs or BackboneJs or KnockoutJs ?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: `4.9k followers` Angular.JS :)

Comment: @Murali Thanks for your guidance but can you specify the reason.

Comment: Dont forget about Durandal http://durandaljs.com/ Personally I use AngularJs with Web API and so far been great.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> It depends on the nature of your application. And since you did not
>   describe it in great detail, it is an impossible question to answer. I
>   find Backbone to be the easiest, but I work in Angular all day.
>   Performance is more up to the coder than the framework, in my opinion.
>
> Are you doing heavy DOM manipulation? I would use jquery and backbone
>
> Very data driven app? Angular with it's nice data binding
>
> Game programming? none, direct to canvas, maybe a game engine - [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19032501/188246)

Also, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5112899/knockout-js-vs-backbone-js

You can check the following source. It's really complete:

http://www.infoq.com/research/top-javascript-mvc-frameworks

Personally, I'd go for Angular just because of its performance, but there are plenty of reasons...

Comment: Thanks for  your quick answer . just one thing let me know that AngularJs is best for which either MVC or MVVM?

Comment: Angular js works for both MVC and MVVM check although it is best for MVVM

Comment: @Nilesh page not found: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5112899/knockout-js-vs-backbone-js

Comment: Is it possible to use mvc views(.cshtml) with angular js routing??

Comment: @Learning check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25785579/is-angular-routing-template-url-support-for-cshtml-file-in-asp-net-mvc-5-projec

Comment: I have already seen that post.i have index.cshtml page which is the first action to run and in this view index.cshtml i have taken ng-view.with this ng-view i want to display my partial view but my angular js controller is not getting fired.

Answer (score 14):

If you are building single page application you need a SPA framework. It should include two-way data-binding, client-side routing, page composition, navigation, screen state management, module system, bundling. You can choose between Angular and Durandal. They both provide very similar functionality, but in my opinion, Durandal is the most complete SPA framework, which is very easy to use. Both Durandal and Angular can be used with Breezejs to build data centric applications.

check [Durandal](http://durandaljs.com/pages/get-started/), [Durandal Auth](https://durandalauth.azurewebsites.net/) and [HotTowel Angular](http://www.johnpapa.net/hot-towel-angular/)

If you are building ASP.NET MVC application, then all you need on the client side is two-way data binding to reduce DOM manipulations. In my opionion, it's an overkill to use angular just for data-binding. Backbone or Knockout are good choices, but Angular can be used as well.

Answer (score 9):

I'm using Knockout with ASP.NET MVC/Web API at work, but I have played with Angular at home and honestly prefer that. Bear in mind though that Knockout solves a much smaller problem than does Angular, the latter being a complete SPA framework (with services, HTML directives etc). To compare apples to apples, you should consider Knockout in tandem with [Durandal](http://durandaljs.com/), as this is a full-blown SPA framework like Angular.

From practical experience I suspect that memory leaks are easier to avoid with Angular than Knockout, since Knockout produces references implicitly as you subscribe to observables (typically via ko.computed) and we had a very hard time trying to track down such memory leaks due to undiciplined taking of Knockout subscriptions without cleaning up. With Angular I couldn't see that you have the same problem, as you don't subscribe directly to mutating variables ("observables"). Instead, the framework is in full control of applying model changes, which might be harder to grasp initially, but ultimately leads to better maintainability.

Answer (score 6):

I have not tried knockout or backbone. With Angular I have worked with ASP.NET MVC. I personally did not like using MVC views. As Angular requires `POJO` (Plain Old JavaScript Objects) , So, I changed to Web Api and Angular. To be honest I am very satisfied with Angular because of following reasons:

- DOM maniuplations are done where they belong.
- Two way binding
- Designed with unit testing
- Services are where they belong
- Designed with HTML5 in mind
- Ability to create HTML markup to suit business needs (directives) and many more.

Comment: I will keep your suggestion in my mind. Thanks

Comment: mvc views cant be used with angular js routing right??