# Creating angularjs multi page app getting following error in chrome console: You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it

Tags: c#, .net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-5

I am getting the following error in Chrome console when I try to go to a second page (click insert from home page). I get the followning JavaScript error:
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module my-pencilbuyer due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'my-pencilbuyer' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

I tried loading the angular-route module. I believe I am going to require routing module to make this work.

Home Controller.cs

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Mvc;

    namespace Test.Controllers
    {
        public class HomeController : Controller
        {
            public ActionResult Index()
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
    }
```

Routing.js

```
    angular.module('MyApp', ['ngRoute'])
        .config(function ($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider
                .when('/', {
                    redirectTo: function () {
                        return '/home';
                    }
                })
                .when('/home', {
                    templateUrl: '/Index.cshtml',
                    controller: 'HomeController'
                })
                .when('/insert', {
                    templateUrl: '/Insert.cshtml',
                    controller: 'PencilController'
                })
                .otherwise({
                    templateUrl: 'Error.html',
                    controller: 'ErrorController'
                });
        });
```

Controller.js

```
    myapp.controller('pencil-controller', function ($scope, pencilService) {

        //Loads all Employee records when page loads
        loadPencil();

        function loadPencil() {
            var PencilRecords = pencilService.getAllPencils();
            PencilRecords.then(function (d) {
                //success
                $scope.Pencil = d.data;
            },
                function () {
                    alert("Error occured while fetching pencil list...");
                });
        }

        $scope.save = function () {
            var Pencil = {
                Name: $scope.Name,
                Image: $scope.Image,
                Price: $scope.Price,
                Description: $scope.Description,
                Buyers: $scope.Buyers
            };
            var saverecords = pencilService.save(Pencil);
            saverecords.then(function (d) {
                if (d.data.success === true) {
                    loadPencil();
                    alert("Pencil added successfully");
                    $scope.resetSave();
                }
                else { alert("Pencil not added."); }
            },
                function () {
                    alert("Error occurred while adding pencil.");
                });
        };
    //reset controls after save operation
        $scope.resetSave = function () {
            $scope.Name = '';
            $scope.Image = '';
            $scope.Price = '';
            $scope.Description = '';
            $scope.Buyers = '';
        };
    });
```

PencilController.cs

```
    using Test.Models;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Mvc;

    namespace Test.Controllers
    {
        public class PencilController : Controller
        {
            // GET: Pencil
            public JsonResult GetPencilHomePage()
            {
                using (Test db = new TestEntities())
                {
                    List<Pencil> pencils = db.Pencils.ToList();
                    return Json(pencils, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                }
            }

            // POST: Pencil
            [HttpPost]
            public JsonResult Insert(Pencil pencil)
            {
                if (pencil != null)
                {
                    using (TestEntities db = new TestEntities())
                    {
                        db.Pencils.Add(pencil);
                        db.SaveChanges();
                        return Json(new { success = true });
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    return Json(new { success = false });
                }
            }

            public ActionResult Insert()
            {
                return View();
            }

            public ActionResult Update()
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
    }
```

Index.cshtml

```
    @section scripts{
        <script src="~/AngularJSApp/Pencil/Module.js"></script>
        <script src="~/AngularJSApp/Pencil/Service.js"></script>
        <script src="~/AngularJSApp/Pencil/Controller.js"></script>
    }
    <div class="container">
        <div class="panel panel-info">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <div class="col-6">
                    Jim
                </div>
                <div class="col-3">
                    <!--@Html.ActionLink("Create", "Insert", "Pencil", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })-->
                    <a data-ng-href="@Url.Action("Insert", "Pencil")" target="_self">Insert</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-3">
                    @Html.ActionLink("Update", "Update", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                <thead style="background-color:lightblue;">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Image</th>
                        <th>Price</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="pencil in Pencils">
                        <td> {{pencil.Name}}</td>
                        <td> {{pencil.Image}}</td>
                        <td>{{pencil.Price}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

```
Insert.cshtml
```

```
    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Insert";
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout1.cshtml";
    }

    <h2>Insert</h2>

    <div id="AddNew" ng-controller="pencil-controller">
                    @*Add New Employee form starts here...*@
                    <form class="form-horizontal" name="AddNewForm">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label">Name</label>
                            <input class="form-control"
                               name="Name" ng-model="Name"
                               placeholder="" />
                            </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label">Image</label>
                            <input class="form-control" name="Image"
                               ng-model="Image" type="text"
                               placeholder="" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label">Price</label>
                            <input class="form-control" name="Price"
                               ng-model="Price" type="email" placeholder="" 
        />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label">Description</label>
                            <input class="form-control" name="Description"
                               ng-model="Description" type="text"
                               placeholder="" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label"> Designation</label>
                        </div>
                    </form>

                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"
                        id="btnSave" ng-click="save()">
                    Save
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"
                        ng-click="resetSave()">
                    Close
                    </button>
        </div>

        @section Scripts{
            <script src="~/AngularJSApp/Routing.js"></script>
        }
```

```
BundleConfig.cs
```

```
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Optimization;

    namespace Test
    {
        public class BundleConfig
        {
            public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
            {
                bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

                bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));


                bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

                bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                      "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"));

                bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                      "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                      "~/Content/site.css"));

                    bundles.Add(new 
    ScriptBundle("~/bundles/angular").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/angular.js"));

                bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/angular- 
   route").Include("~/Scripts/angular-route.js"));
                }
            }
       }
```

Update.cshtml

```
        @{
            ViewBag.Title = "Update";
            Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
        }

        <h2>Update</h2>
```

Module.js

```
    var myapp;
    (function () {
        myapp = angular.module('my-pencilbuyer', []);
    })();
```

_Layout.cshtml

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial- 
   scale=1.0">
        <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
        @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/angular")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/angular-route")
    </head>
    <body ng-app="my-pencilbuyer">
        <!--<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                @Html.ActionLink("Application name", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>-->
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Service.js

```
myapp.service('pencilService', function ($http) {

    this.getAllPencils = function () {

        return $http.get("/Pencil/GetPencilHomePage");
    };

    this.save = function (Pencil) {
        var request = $http({
            method: 'post',
            url: '/Pencil/Insert',
            data: Pencil
        });
        return request;
    }
});
```

Comment: Off topic but this has to be the first time I've seen someone use C# with Angular.

Answer (score 0):

You have created two different AngularJS apps. With this line in `Routing.js` you are creating an app registered as `MyApp` and injecting `ngRoute`:

```
angular.module('MyApp', ['ngRoute'])
```

In `Module.js` you are creating a completely separate app registered as `my-pencilbuyer` and no injections:

```
var myapp;
(function () {
    myapp = angular.module('my-pencilbuyer', []);
})();
```

Looks like you need to move the `.config` from `MyApp` into `my-pencilbuyer` and get rid of `MyApp` altogether.

Comment: so I did what you suggested and  commented out the route.js file and removed it from loading in the cshtml file. Now I am getting error on main page:  http://localhost:60948/Home/Index.cshtml 404 (Not Found) and Failed to load template: Home/Index.cshtml (HTTP status: 404 Not Found). Also still getting same error on insert page as original description. Any suggestions? Thanks! Forgot to mention that I added the ngRoute where I created angular app.

Comment: Because you are essentially using two routing systems (one client and one server) there is likely more that needs to be done to make it work. [Here's a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29903751/angularjs-routing-with-asp-net-mvc) that might help. My answer was to address your [$injector:nomod] error.