# Angular routing for ASP.NET MVC not working

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am developing a ASP.NET MVC - SPA website and I am using AngularJS. I have referred various articles given on the net. I am using `ng-view`, `ngRoute` and `$routeProvider` to achieve this but it is not working at all in my case. The code I have used for the routing is given below:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutPersonal.cshtml";
}
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h3>Questions</h3>
@*@Html.Action("Index","Question")*@
<div ng-app="overflowApp" ng-controller="overflowCtrl">
    <p><a href="#/">Main</a></p>

    <a href="#questions">Questions</a>
    <a href="#users">Users</a>
    <a href="#answers">Answers</a>
    <div ng-view></div>
</div>
    @section scripts{
        <script>
            function overflowController($scope, $http) {
                $scope.testList = ['a', 'b'];
            }

            var overflowApp = angular.module("overflowApp", ['ngSanitize', 'ngRoute']);
            overflowApp.controller("overflowCtrl", overflowController);
            overflowApp.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
                $routeProvider     
                    .when("/questions", {
                        templateUrl : "../Question"
                    })
                    .when("/users", {
                        templateUrl: "../Questions/users"
                    })
                    .when("/answers", {
                        templateUrl: "../Questions/answers"
                    });
            }]);
        </script>
    }
```

The URLs being displayed when I hover over the hyperlinks look like `http://localhost:49910/#/questions` and it doesn't load the view it is supposed to. Please help me out.

Comment: look at your network tab, what is the link being requested

Comment: Have checked this out: [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25785579/is-angular-routing-template-url-support-for-cshtml-file-in-asp-net-mvc-5-projec)?

Comment: @MihailStancescu: I have modified the code accordingly but no luck!

Comment: Try using the `templateUrl: Questions`, because that should be a request for ASP.NET MVC to handle to be able to return the compiled HTML from the Razor view.