# How to redirect to cshtml page using $stateProvider in angularjs

Tags: asp.net, angularjs

I'm working on asp.net project.
I tried to link cshtml page in angular .config file using $stateprovider.
But, it didn't work.
Here are some codes.
Define route in app.config:

```
$stateProvider
   .state('login', {
       url: '/login',
       templateUrl: 'View/Account/Login.cshtml'                
   });
```

And Login.cshtml is:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<head>
    <base href="/login" />
</head>

<style>
    .bg {
        transform: translateX(-50%);
        position: fixed;
        display: none;
        opacity: 0.5;
        z-index: 10;
        left: 50%;
        top: 0;
    }
</style>
<img src="" class="bg" />
<div ng-include src="'/Scripts/app/account/template/login.html'"></div>
```

But when I tried to go '/login' using $state.go("login"), it didn't work.
Why? Is this impossible? Please help me to solve this puzzle.

Comment: Please check this out.
I hope It will help you.
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25785579/does-angular-routing-template-url-support-cshtml-files-in-asp-net-mvc-5-projec)

Comment: Thanks Antonio Cholony

Answer (score 1):

Please try this method.

```
.when('/order', {
    templateUrl: '/Order/Create',
    controller: 'ngOrderController' // Angular Controller
})
```

For details, you need to check below answer;
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25785579/does-angular-routing-template-url-support-cshtml-files-in-asp-net-mvc-5-projec)

I hope this will help you.