# Integrating Angular into existing MVC views or a separate solution from scratch using pure Angular & .Net core Web API

Tags: angular, performance, routes, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

I am currently working on an Enterprise application built using **.Net core**. Widely used **View-components** inside **MVC Views**.

We received a request to redesign UI with new look and additional features. Now, I was asked if I can use existing solution with **Angular** to incorporate the changes and integrate in existing MVC views or create new pages/modules.

I would like to know if loading up additional Angular scripts into existing MVC views would lead to any performance issues. Also, I need to favor both the **MVC routing** and **Angular routing** mechanisms.

Additional task such as doing ng-build for compiling typescript files separately to build solution and adding bundled Angular files into layout file for loading Angular scripts. Upon every deployment update bundled script files.

On the other hand, create a new solution from scratch using pure **Angular** for front end and a separate solution using **.Net core Web API**.

Please let me know the recommended way to start with.

Comment: You can use build in Angular template of VS 2019

Answer (score 2):

I think the first option is too much of a hassle. I had to make the exact same decision a while ago and decided to go with the second choice because of the following:

1. It's much easier to create/update/build a pure angular application
2. Not waisting time to merge the two worlds
3. The SPA world, differs from MVC. You can still use the views and get them on demand but it kind of beats the point of the framework
4. Creating a .net core api, seems the better choice. A pure rest api is a much easier thing to do
5. Large enough application will start to take too much time to build from outside angular-cli in visual studio.

Case in point [check this guide](https://www.mithunvp.com/angular-asp-net-mvc-5-angular-cli-visual-studio-2017/). Look at the comments. A very simple integration that caused people even up to two days to get it working.

If you think that it's ok and you really want to go for it, you can check this great answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25785579/does-angular-routing-template-url-support-cshtml-files-in-asp-net-mvc-5-projec)